# Kotlin Extension Function

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

Considering this:

```
MyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

can be simplified to this:

```
inline fun View.setVisible() = apply { visibility = View.VISIBLE }

MyView.setVisible()
```

Or this if you prefer:

```
inline infix fun View.vis(vis: Int) = apply { visibility = vis }
MyView vis View.VISIBLE
```

Is there anyway of accomplish the same by doing this:

```
MyView.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bit odd for a "getter" to modify state but you can use an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties):

```
val View.VISIBLE: Unit
    get() {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

And you could also make it return the new visibility value or return itself so that you can potentially chain calls.

```
val View.VISIBLE: Int
    get() {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        return visibility
    }
```

or

```
val View.VISIBLE: View
    get() = apply { visibility = View.VISIBLE }
```

Comment: yes you right it is weird. This is not a real scenario, was just messing around with stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) property with a getter like this:

```
val View.visible: View
    get() = apply { visibility = View.VISIBLE }
```

With the usage:

```
 myView.visible
```

However, keep in mind that properties with side effects in getters are generally discouraged (see also: [Functions vs Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties)), and this behavior is rather confusing for a property.